# Missing "empty" records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'll try to make it short: I'm new to LINQ. So there.

I have three tables, that i have EntityFrameworked into my solution:

```
Employees        Desks          Rooms
--------------   ------------   ------------
FirstName        DeskId         RoomId
DeskId           RoomId         RoomName
                 Color          HasWindows
                 Width
```

I need a view with:

```
Employee   Room name              
----------------------------------
Lumberg    Corner Office         
Milton     Storage in basement   
Peter      Cubicle 214
```

So, I created an `EmployeeRoomListViewModel`, and fill it using `JOINs` in my LINQ. No sweat, except 
I'm missing some records. Namely those Employees without an assigned desk (`DeskId` is null). I need those also.

Here's my LINQ:

```
from Emp in db.Employees 
join D in db.Desks on D.DeskId equals Emp.DeksId
join R in db.Rooms on D.RoomId equals R.RoomId
          select new EmployeeRoomListViewModel
          {
              Employee = Emp.FirstName,
              Room = R.RoomName
          }).ToList();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of joins you should define proper relations in your entities. LINQ isn't a replacement for SQL, it's a query language on top of an ORM. It's the *ORM's* job to take care of generating queries and joins. All this could be replaced with `db.Employees.Select(emp=>new EmployeeRoomListViewModel{Employee=emp.FirstName,Room=emp.Desk?.Room}).ToList()`

Comment: [MetadataType(typeof(Orders_MD))]
    public partial class Orders
    {
        public List<OrderLines> myLines { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Orders_MD
    {
        [Display(Name = "ID")]     
        public int oId { get; set; }
 
 ...
    }

---

    [MetadataType(typeof(OrderLines_MD))]
    public partial class OrderLines
    {
        public Orders myOrder { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Orders_MD
    {
        [Display(Name = "Date")]     
        public DateTime orderDate { get; set; }

 ...
    }

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have tried using navigation properties to bind two entity classes together, but I get nulls when browsing a result. See partial class defs above. (How the h... does one add a longer follow-up question in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use DefaultIfEmpty clause for Left Outer Join

```
from Emp in db.Employees 
  join D in db.Desks on D.DeskId equals Emp.DeksId into employeeDesks 
    from ed in employeeDesks.DefaultIfEmpty() 
  join R in db.Rooms on D.RoomId equals R.RoomId into deskRooms
    from dr in deskRooms.DefaultIfEmpty()
  select new EmployeeRoomListViewModel
  {
      Employee = Emp.FirstName,
      Room = R.RoomName
  }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct but you just need to add "Into Alias" and DefaultIfEmpty() in them.

```
from Emp in db.Employees 
join Des in db.Desks on Des.DeskId equals Emp.DeksId into SomeThing 
from Des in SomeThing.DefaultIfEmpty();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem

```
from Emp in db.Employees 
join D in db.Desks on D.DeskId equals Emp.DeksId into desklist from deskjoin in 
desklist.DefaultIfEmpty()
join R in db.Rooms on deskjoin.RoomId equals R.RoomId into roomlist from roomjoin in roomlist.DefaultIfEmpty() select new EmployeeRoomListViewModel
                      {
                          Employee = Emp.FirstName,
                          Room = roomjoin.RoomName
                      }).ToList();
```

first time you need to take left join employees table with Desks table and then you need to take left join with result of employees and Desk table join

In this "into desklist from deskjoin in desklist.DefaultIfEmpty()" is used for left join query